# admin panel gives access to specific page

Tags: laravel, controller, admin, middleware

I want to make the access to /Inscription in my website unavalible untill the admin gives access to it in the /admin page soo when the guest goes to /inscription he gets a message "unavalible" untill the admin goes to /admin and unlock it

i tried to make it using the middleware on laravel but i doesn't seem the work .
i did php artisan make:middleware Access 
and coded and made a view unavalible i want it to load when he goes to /Inscription

kernel.php :

```
  protected $middleware = [
       .....
    \App\Http\Middleware\Access::class,
];
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'access' => \App\Http\Middleware\Access::class,
```

the access middleware :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Access
{

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
 echo "mwajer";
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

Comment: add to your `route::get('/inscription', Controller@method)->middleware('access');`

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>['access']], function (){
       Route::get('/inscription', MyInscriptionController@index)->name('inscription');
       //All your routes that you needs admin approval here
});
```

Put all your restricted route inside the group, also it is a good idea to use route naming. You can add multiple middleware to the group